# I have conflict with Smarty engine and type="text/x-tmpl"

Tags: templates, smarty

I use smarty engine to template (don't judge, is how i am used to do it) and for an upload form I have beside the form this script, and I don't know how to escape the `{%` and `%}`.

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
                    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
                <tr class="template-download fade">
                    {% if (file.error) { %}
                <td></td>
                <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
                <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
                    {% } else { %}
                <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
                    {% } %}</td>
                <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
    </td>
</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Now the `{%` and `%}` are giving me problems. How can I make them to be literal?
I also use the `{literal}{/literal}` but that tags stil gives me errors.

Comment: What errors do you get when you use `{literal}{/literal}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to change default smarty delimiters?

example.php:

```
$smarty->left_delimiter = '<!--{';
$smarty->right_delimiter = '}-->';

$smarty->assign('foo', 'bar');
$smarty->assign('name', 'Albert');
$smarty->display('example.tpl');

?>
```

example.tpl:

```
Welcome <!--{$name}--> to Smarty
<script language="javascript">
  var foo = <!--{$foo}-->;
  function dosomething() {
    alert("foo is " + foo);
  }
  dosomething();
</script>
```

See more on http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.escaping.tpl